# blocking time in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, blocking

What does *blocking time* mean in Google Chrome developer tools and why is it so big?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue with a 30 second "blocking" time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Blocking" is the time the request spent waiting for an already
>   established connection to become available (i.e. we're reusing a
>   connection that may be used to transfer another resource at the time
>   the request was started).
>
> via https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/8jpALcJqkUM

There are a couple of potential solutions to this, split requests out into different sub-domains for other assets.  Or look into SPDY

Comment: Are there another solutions? Requests into different sub-domain doens't fit for the app logic and SPDY doens't look really usefull.

Comment: There is something in your infrastructure that is blocking for 22seconds.  That is really bad.